# Standard file format for encryption keys?

Tags: encryption, file-format

Is there a standard file format for public/private key pairs?

Something similar to x509 for certificates.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SSH public key format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt) (also used by their private keys) is fairly standard.